# OpenLayers 5 ExtentInteraction getTopLeft etc

Tags: reactjs, openlayers

I'm using OpenLayers 5 ExtentInteraction to build a bounding box. This is how I'm implementing this feature:

```
const vectorSource = new VectorSource({
    url: 'data/geojson/countries.geojson',
    format: new GeoJSON(),
});

const extent = new ExtentInteraction({ condition: shiftKeyOnly });
/**
 *
 * @param {*} props
 */
function OpenLayer(props) {
    const [map, setMap] = useState();

    const mapElement = useRef();
    mapElement.current = map;

    useEffect(() => {
        const initialMap = new Map({
            target: mapElement.current,
            layers: [
                new TileLayer({
                    source: new OSM(),
                }),
                new VectorLayer({
                    source: vectorSource,
                }),
            ],
            view: new View({
                center: [0, 0],
                zoom: 0,
            }),
        });
        setMap(initialMap);
        initialMap.addInteraction(extent);
    }, []);
    /**
     *
     * @param {*} props
     */
    const extentChange = () => {
        const topLeft = olExtent.getTopLeft(extent);
        const topRight = olExtent.getTopRight(extent);
        const bottomLeft = olExtent.getBottomLeft(extent);
        const bottomRight = olExtent.getBottomRight(extent);
        console.log('topLeft: ', topLeft, topRight, bottomLeft, bottomRight);
    };

    return (
        <div className="mapRow">
            <div ref={mapElement} onClick={extentChange} className="map-container" />
        </div>
    );
}
```

The console.log values come back as undefined on the extentChange(). I did notice that I can simply console.log the extent and it returns an array of that I assume is the four points I need, but I'm not sure if that's the case. Here is what I'm talking about:

```
    const extent = new ExtentInteraction({ condition: shiftKeyOnly });

    console.log('extent: ', extent);
```

[image: This returns the given object with this array:]

Ultimately, I'm wondering if those values in the object are the equivalent of results that would provided by getTopLeft, getTopRight, getBottomRight, and getBottomLeft? Also, how do I apply those methods to extent const?

Comment: `getTopLeft`, etc take an extent, not an extent interaction, so you need `olExtent.getTopLeft(extent.getExtent())`

Answer (score 0):

@Mike had the correct answer, but I didn't see an option to post his answer so here it is:

getTopLeft, etc take an extent, not an extent interaction, so you need olExtent.getTopLeft(extent.getExtent())